I am getting error "List secrets contains repeated instances" trying to run New-AzCloudService:
I am trying to creating a new instance of Azure Cloud Services Extended Support (CSES) "New-AzCloudService: List secrets contains repeated instances...".
It is a new instance, so it is not a matter of the certificate that I am trying to add already exists on the machine.

I found the problem. I have 3 certificates and I was creating 1 secretGroup (New-AzCloudServiceVaultSecretGoupObject) for each one and having all 3 added to the osProfile.secret.
But what I should be doing is getting the 3 certificates and have all 3 added to the same secretGroup and then just add that single secretGroup to the OSProfile.secret.
